# use a script to enter a password. Bash &| Python

Tags: python, bash, echo, webdav

I am trying to create a script to mount a series of webDAV folders in Linux.

now this is possible when executing:

```
sudo mount -t davfs  -o  noexec http://dav.website.com /mnt/
```

The problem is, the user is asked to enter credentials as soon as the command is executed...

```
enter username:
enter password:
```

now I have the same password and username for the entire series of the online DAV folders

Is there a way for me to write a bash or bash embedded python script?

I have tried the following

```
sudo mount -t davfs  -o  noexec http://dav.website.com /mnt/ |echo username\npassowrd
```

,but got no sucess.

I really have to use the

```
sudo mount -t davfs  -o  noexec http://dav.website.com /mnt/
```

method.

Comment: Look into expect, it's made for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

With a [Here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
sudo mount -t davfs -o noexec http://dav.website.com /mnt/ << EOF
username
password
EOF
```

For more security, use a [file for credentials](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs2#Storing_credentials).